# preventDefault() on a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know if there's a way to preventDefault(), but on a timer, so default actions are restored after a certain time?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function setResetInterval(bool){
  var el = $('article');
  if(bool){
        timer = setInterval(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('default prevented');
          e.preventDefault();
      }, 500);
    },1000);
  }else{
    clearInterval(timer); 
  }
}

if(object.touch.touch){
    object.header.menu_button.attr('href',null);
    object.touch.articles = $('article');
    object.content_blocks.on('click','article',{},function(e){
    object.touch.articles.removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    e.stopPropagation();
    setResetInterval(true);
         setTimeout(
                function() { setResetInterval(false); }, 500);
    });
}
```

Problem is, the function is called after the clickthrough and the action is not prevented.  The alternative is the prevent the default action on click, which stop scrolling on mobile devices.

Thinking about it more clearly, the real problem is the click tag in question is basically the entire screen width on mobile.

Comment: Do a count down with settimeout after the action and change the target id or class to something that will do the default action.

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Cayce said, one way to approach this is to tie the functionality to a class you later remove.

**[Demo Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/f1hbwjzg/)**

In the example, the default will be prevented as long as the div has the `.red` class, the `setTimeout` will remove the class after 3 seconds.

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.red', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('I only show up while default is prevented');
});

$('body').on('click', 'div', function () {
    console.log('I will always show up');
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $('div').removeClass('red');
},3000);
```

Comment: That's a clever solution, I appreciate the answer!